# Laplace Heaviside function,how can I continue?

Tags: laplace-transform

I have to find the Laplace transform of the function $H(t-a)t^{n}$.
That's what I have done so far:
$$L\{H(t-a)t^{n}\}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}H(t-a)t^{n}dt=\int_{a}^{\infty}e^{-st}t^{n}dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-s(t+a)}(t+a)^{n}dt $$

Could you tell me how I can continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this formula can help us, besides to @dato's way. You know that $\mathcal{L}\{\mathscr{U}(t-a)\}=\frac{e^{-as}}{s}, a>0$. And $$\mathcal{L}\{t^nf(t)\}=(-1)^n\bigg(\mathcal{L}(f(t))\bigg)^{(n)}$$ Now let think about $\big(\frac{e^{-as}}{s}\big)^{(n)}$. Using Maple, I found:

$$n=1\to \left(\frac{e^{-as}}{s}\right)'=-\exp(-as)\frac{as+1}{s^2}\\ n=2\to \left(\frac{e^{-as}}{s}\right)''=\exp(-as)\frac{a^2s^2+2as+2}{s^3}\\ n=3\to \left(\frac{e^{-as}}{s}\right)'''=-\exp(-as)\frac{a^3s^3+3a^2s^2+6as+6}{s^4} $$ And so I think the possible pattern could be $$(-1)^n\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}s^{n-k}a^{n-k}}{s^{n+1}}$$

Comment: This result seems to be wrong... why don't use the General Leibniz rule with $f(s)=e^{-as}$ and $g(s)=\frac{1}{s}$? Observing that $f^{(n)}=(-1)^n a^n e^{-as}$ and $g^{(n)}=(-1)^n\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$, we find $$\mathcal{L}(H(t-a)t^n)= (-1)^n\left( \frac{e^{-as}}{s}\right)^{(n)}=(-1)^n e^{-as}\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}k!\frac{a^{n-k}}{s^{k+1}}=(-1)^n \frac{e^{-as}}{s^{n+1}}n!e_n(as)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1,as)}{s^{n+1}}$$ where $e_n(z)$ is the [exponential sum function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFunction.html) and $\Gamma(n,x)$ is the Incomplete Gamma Function.

Comment: @alexjo: I fixed it.

Comment: @B.S. you have to fix the sum too..$\sum_0^n$ and not $\sum_0^{n-1}$

Comment: @alexjo: I think I pushed a wrong key on the keyword. Thanks for remarking that awful typo.

Comment: @B.S. I get $$I_{n}=e^{-sa}\Sigma_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a^{n+1-k}}{s^{k}}\frac{n!}{(n-k+1)!}+\frac{n!I_{0}}{s^{n}}$$  
where $I_{0}=\frac{e^{-sa}}{s}$ .Is it right?

Comment: @B.S. My result is the same as yours,but instead of the $(-1)^{n}$ I have $e^{-sa}$ ..

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain directly from the integral
$$\mathcal{L}\{H(t-a)t^{n}\}=\int_{a}^{\infty}e^{-st}t^{n}dt=\frac{1}{s^{n+1}}\int_{as}^{\infty}e^{-z}z^{n}dz= \frac{1}{s^{n+1}}\Gamma(n+1,as)$$ recalling the integral expression of [incomplete Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) for integer $n$
$$
\Gamma(n,x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-z}z^{n-1}dz.
$$

**NOTE** Another useful methodology may be the following.

Observing that $$H(t-a)t^n=H(t-a)(t-a+a)^n=H(t-a)\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(t-a)^ka^{n-k}$$ the Laplace transform becomes
$$
\mathcal{L}\{H(t-a)t^n\}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}\mathcal{L}\{H(t-a)(t-a)^k\}
$$
recalling that $\mathcal{L}\{H(t-a)f(t-a)\}=e^{-as}F(s)$. Using $\mathcal{L}\{t^n\}=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$, we obtain
$$
\mathcal{L}\{H(t-a)t^n\}=e^{-as}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}\frac{k!}{s^{k+1}}=\frac{n!e^{-as}}{s^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(as)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}=\frac{1}{s^{n+1}}n!e^{-as}\sum_{\nu=0}^n\frac{(as)^{\nu}}{\nu!}
$$
and recalling that 
$$
\Gamma(n,z)=(n-1)!e^{-z}\sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1}\frac{z^{\nu}}{\nu!}
$$
is the incomplete Gamma function for integer $n$, we obtain finally
$$
\mathcal{L}\{H(t-a)t^n\}=\frac{1}{s^{n+1}}\Gamma(n+1,as).
$$

Comment: So, is it necessary to use the formula of $\Gamma(n,x)$ ?Because, I haven't get taught it..

Comment: @evinda Yes. You can find more on the incomplete Gamma at link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: nice..thank you very much!!!

Comment: I have also tried to integrate by part.I found the recursive relation: $I_{n}=\frac{e^{-sa}a^{n}}{s}+\frac{nI_{n-1}}{s^{2}}$,from which I found that:$$I_{n}=e^{-sa}\Sigma_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a^{n+1-k}}{s^{2k-1}}\frac{n!}{(n-k+1)!}+\frac{n!I_{0}}{s^{2n}}$$ ,where $$I_{0}=\frac{e^{-sa}}{s}$$ .Could you tell me if it is right?? Also,could you tell me how I can calculate the sum that I found??

Comment: Integrating by parts I obtain $I_n=\frac{nI_{n-1}}{s}+a^nI_0$ where $I_0=\frac{e^{-as}}{s}$. This result is just the [recurrence formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.8.E2) for the Incomplete Gamma Function. [Here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8) you can find more useful formulas.

Comment: @alexjo: Thanks for pointing me that typo. Thanks. ;-) +1

Comment: @alexjo I calculated it again..now I found the same result like yours. But how can I verify the result?

Answer (score 1):

put $t+\alpha=m$

then $dt=dm$

so we have

$  e^{-s(t+\alpha)}*(t+\alpha)^n=e^{-sm}m^ndm$

you can integrate by part

Comment: That is the same result that I found at the second step, before I replaced it with the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-s(t+a)}(t+a)^{n}dt$ .So,I shouldn't have changed it..right?

Comment: no just  use definition of integration by part and follow it,happy new year and merry christmas

Comment: I wish you also a happy new year! But how often do I have to make then integration by part ?

Comment: you mean during the process?you will finish it,but if something is repeating,then you can denote  result one by $I$ and  then you may get $2*I$ is equal something and you should divide by $2$,http://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/int_by_parts/

Comment: But the power $n$ will be getting smaller after each process. Or am I wrong? So, how can I find again $I$?

Comment: http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=e%5E%28-sx%29x%5En&random=false    there is  example of this integrator,sorry i am bussy now,maybe someone help you